# Flippable atomic boolean

Tags: c++, c++17, atomic

I was trying to implement a boolean that can be atomically flipped.
The [suggestion on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9806613/2436175) is to use an integer.
This would be my implementation.

```
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>


class flippable_atomic_bool {
    std::atomic<int> state;
    public:
    flippable_atomic_bool() : state(0){}
    explicit flippable_atomic_bool(bool init) : state(static_cast<int>(init)) {}
    explicit flippable_atomic_bool(const flippable_atomic_bool& other) = default;
    flippable_atomic_bool& operator =(const flippable_atomic_bool& other) = default;
    void flip() {
        state ^= static_cast<int>(true);
    }
    operator bool() const {
        return static_cast<bool>(state);
    }
};


int main() {
    {
        flippable_atomic_bool a(true);
        std::cout << static_cast<bool>(a) << std::endl;
        a.flip();
        std::cout << static_cast<bool>(a) << std::endl;
    }
    {
        flippable_atomic_bool a{false};
        std::cout << static_cast<bool>(a) << std::endl;
        a.flip();
        std::cout << static_cast<bool>(a) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

[Outputs](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1f5926e43958510)

> ```
> 1
> 0
> 0
> 1
> ```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default constructor might be surprising to those familiar with `std::atomic<T>` in C++17, which [default-constructs to an *uninitialised* state](https://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/issue2334), rather than to a default `T`.  That said, this behaviour is correct for C++20, so a good choice!

There's no benefit to `explicit` copy-constructor - that can never be an implicit conversion.

The defaulted copy constructor and assignment are misleading - since `state` is not copyable, this causes them to be deleted, so we should write `= delete` instead of `= default` or (better) just omit them.

It's interesting that we write a literal `0` as initializer for `state`, but then use `static_cast<int>(true)` in the `^=` implementation.

Since `bool` and `int` are interconvertible, we can write the whole thing without casts (I compiled with `g++ -Wconversion -Wuseless-cast`, amongst other options):

```
class flippable_atomic_bool
{
    std::atomic<int> state;
public:
    flippable_atomic_bool()
        : state{}
    {}
    explicit flippable_atomic_bool(bool init)
        : state{init}
    {}

    void flip()
    {
        state ^= 1;
    }
    operator bool() const
    {
        return state;
    }
};
```

---

The test program doesn't demonstrate much of relevance.  I would expect to show several threads toggling the atomic a few thousand times each, and demonstrate that the end state is consistent.

It's not hard to do that, if we build using OpenMP:

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    auto a = flippable_atomic_bool{false};

#pragma omp parallel for num_threads(5)
    for (long i = 0;   i < 100000001;  ++i) {
        a.flip();
    }

    std::cout << std::boolalpha << a << '\n';
    return !a;
}
```

We could gain more confidence by running that race a few hundred times, and checking we always get the same result.

Comment: Thanks! I was aware the casts were not really necessary, but I thought they would make the intent more explicit. I was thinking, would it make sense to use `int_fast8_t` in place of `int`?

Comment: I was also thinking that the `explicit` for `flippable_atomic_bool(bool init)` doesn't help me much, and in fact it prevents me from doing [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization#Notes). What do I lose by removing it?

Comment: Since the copy constructor is defaulted, which makes it deleted, then you lose nothing by removing the `explicit` - it still can't be called!  (If you think you're using it, it's likely you're going via the conversion-to-bool operator without realising it.  And that's fine.)

Comment: If we change to `std::int_fast8_t`, we might need explicit casts in some places for platforms where that's narrower than `int`.  `int` is supposed to be the architectures "natural type" for arithmetic, so my inclination is to stick with that.